What's the performance difference between an SKPath draw and individual line draws?
Technically I'm using SkiaSharp but this is a general Skia query.
Let's say I have hundreds of points and I'm drawing straight lines or arcs between them.
I could either iterate over each one doing individual draw calls for basic line or arc draws.
Or I could iterate over each one building an SKPath and then drawing that in one draw function call.
Is there any performance difference between the two? Is one more favourable over the other?
Additional - I'll be reusing the SkPath with a reset call before each frame, and this will be firing off every render loop.

General rule of thumb: minimize number of draw calls. Might not matter much when using CPU-based Skia. (I expect) a large difference when using GPU-based Skia. SkiaSharp Version 3.0 will support GPU. [I'll also mention SKPicture, which is useful for data that is not changing frame-to-frame, and doesn't fit into a single SKPath.]
